# how to get data from a database of another activity in android

Tags: android, database, media-player

in my app in the first activity i have created a database which stores the songs that are in my device SD card. I want play all those songs one by one. In another activity i have a play button when the button is clicked i want to play the songs stored in the database of my first activity.

now i have created the database and stored the songs but i don't know to get songs from that database.
Following is the code of database where i store the list of songs

```
private Handler songsDatabase = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
                File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                Log.e("location",""+extStore);
                System.gc();
                final String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
                Log.e("media",""+proj.length);

                musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
                Log.e("media1",""+musiccursor);

                SQLiteDatabase db;
                db = openOrCreateDatabase("TestData.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                db.setVersion(1);
                db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                db.setLockingEnabled(true);
                final String CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs (bpm INTEGER,songname TEXT);";
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES);
                Log.e("media","table created");
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                cursor=managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);

                while(cursor.moveToNext()) 
                {

//                  Long duration = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.DURATION));
//                  String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA));
                    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    values.put("bpm", 0); 
                    values.put("songname", title);  
                    db.insert("songs", null, values);
                    // handle song here
                }

                    Log.e("media","insered");
                    Cursor cx = db.rawQuery("select * from songs"  , null);
                    if (cx != null ) 
                    {
                        if  (cx.moveToFirst()) 
                        {
                            do 
                            {   
                                int bpm=cx.getInt(0);
                                String songname =cx.getString(1);
                                Log.e("songs","bpm "+bpm+" songname "+songname);
                            }while (cx.moveToNext());
                        }
                    }
//              Log.e("sql","counter" +counter);

                db.close();         
        }
    };
```

how to do this.... please help me

Comment: Paste the code you use to save the data... it will make it easy for us to tell you how to retrieve the data again.

Comment: After this line  Cursor cx = db.rawQuery("select * from songs"  , null);
 check the count of Cursor by cx.getCount()..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need to create ContentProvider around your database, so you can easily access it from different activities. Fill from one and play from the other etc.